# Spring boot javascript not executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I'm working on a spring mvc application, and my javascript is directly in my html files. For whatever reason, this code is never executed. I even have a coded in breakpoint and it's never hit. No errors or anything are thrown from the chrome debugger. It seems like nothing runs at all, even when I write jibberish. I've tried explicitly defining jquery in case there were any conflicts, but there is nothing. This is the code on the bottom of my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        debugger;
        alert( "ready!" );

    });
</script>
```

Comment: It may be helpful with we can see the HTML file with the relevant parts highlighted.

Comment: You're right, I'll keep that in mind. Still kinda new at this whole thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use any script inside the `script` tag which is used to link a js file. Create another `script` tag and paste your code in it:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("ready!");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That did it, looking now it makes total sense. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help you. @SamRasmussen